# What are the effects of small spark gaps on connectors?

Tags: wiring, wire, tesla-coil, copper, arc

I was reading about the '4th Pin' problem that effects almost all modern iPhone users. It is where the 4th pin on the lightning connector turn black and eventually will not work until it is scraped or dissolved with alcohol. After reading an article on this, the most plausible cause for it appears to be that the connector is seated in a way to cause a small spark gap. The article was a little terse on specifics though, I was wondering:

1. Is sublimation occurring where the spark forms? If so where does the vapor go?
2. Why is the residue a black color?
3. Are there any other causes for the black residue? Oxidation?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4th pin (5th counted the other way, as is technically correct) is the power pin. As such, it probably has the highest current flowing through it and the least voltage protection.

This is likely to create an inductive spike, and hence spark, as you pull the plug. The spark oxidises the metal of the connector. Although it looks gold-flashed, the gold is extremely thin and the underlying copper oxidises. Copper oxide is black, so is almost certainly what you see.

Copper oxide is also a poor conductor, so it needs to be cleaned off. Mechanical scrubbing or cleaning solvent are two ways to achieve this.

To prevent the problem, power off the thing you have plugged into. That way, no current will be flowing when you yank the lightning connector out.

(Golden Rule No.1 for all electrical and electronics engineers: POWER OFF BEFORE YOU DISCONNECT! Golden rule for sales & marketing: sell hot-plugging to shorten the product lifecycle and bring 'em back for the upgrade model)

Comment: I wish I could give more points for pointing out 1) the correct pin numbering 2) reiterating that sales teams lie. 
Just to summarize the original answer, the spark vaporizes the gold cover, and then exposed copper oxidizes?

Comment: "Gold flash" actually means a very thin layer of gold, so I would say it is indeed gold-flashed... It's just not gold-plated, which would imply a thicker, more controlled gold plating. A proper power connector should probably have a gold plating thickness of at least 30 to 50 μ", preferably more, but anything called gold flash is likely no more than 1 μ".

Comment: @LiamKelly A thin gold layer like this is not a neat, solid sheet but a kind of jumble of atoms going mostly in the right sort of place, like a ball pool with not quite enough in to hide the bottom. A spark will just make it messier - evaporate some, mix some down into the copper, mix some copper up where it reacts with the oxygen ions also produced by the spark. Flashing (vacuum deposition) can be used to give a decently thick layer, but how quick do you want your product to wear out?